# Unity overlay objects on top of device camera (AR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, htc-vive

I am working with the Vive and a mobile tablet. The tablet has a tracker attached and then there is another tracker in the room.

On the tablet I output the devices camera on the screen and adjust the position and rotation according the devices position. What I want to do now is render the other tracker's position AR-like on top of the camera output.

I tried googling this, but so far I could only find how to make AR with Vuforia, which I don't need.

I really just need some keywords to start searching, because I don't really know how begin.

Comment: i can't recognize what you want :D but every thing in AR is posible and easy- what mean's top of the camera out put ? you want add the object on the camera image ?

Comment: @ehsanwwe Yes. Scaled, rotated and positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

there is allot of way for making AR . 
i propose you using API - like

- Vuforia AR package
- ARtoolkit
- wikitude
- etc ( by searching "Augmented reality API )

in other way ( i try it allot )
you should use corner detection and using feature extraction method ( every things under "ImageProcessing" science )

- it if you don't want work with image Marker or target - you should get data from sensors in mobile application is easy but in other you should add sensors ( gyroscope and acceleration meter )

i hope i got what you want,

for image processing use openCV in C++ or java / emguCV in C#

### if your problem was shader in unity

you could add a background layer in a unlit shader;
and put the Plane ( textured with camera render ) front of view of you unity camera object

Comment: I have the coordinates already, so I don't need any feature detection or marks on the object. I use trackers and can get their positions easily. Is there any way to just overlay the 3d object on top of the device camera?

Comment: @sollniss in my answer i said it my firend - you could add a background layer in a unlit shader; and put the Plane ( textured with camera render ) front of view of you unity camera object